# Nutritional difference between Sweet and Regular potatoes.

Tags: diet, carbohydrate

I've been wondering about this for some time now.

A LOT of diets include sweet potatoes as a source of complex carbs, which would be just fine, if I lived in US. Since I don't there aren't any available to me ( and no, it's not the price, you just CAN'T buy them).

Therefore, could the [sweet potatoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_potato) be substitued with [regular potatoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato)?

Comment: This question is off topic now, regarding the [FAQ].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the surface (by nutrient breakdown), they look pretty similar except that a sweet potato has massively more vitamin A. According to [Dr. Mirkin](http://www.drmirkin.com/nutrition/sweet_potatoes_not_white.html):

> 7-ounce white potato with skin: 220
>   calories, 5g protein, 51g carbs, 20mg
>   calcium, 115mg phosphorus, 2.8mg iron,
>   16mg sodium, 844mg potassium, 4g
>   fiber, .22mg thiamin, .07mg
>   riboflavin, 3.3mg niacin, 16mg vitamin
>   C
>
> 7-ounce sweet potato: 208 calories,
>   3.5g protein, 49g carbs, 56mg calcium, 110mg phosphorus, 1mg iron, 20mg
>   sodium, 693mg potassium, 5g fiber,
>   4350 RE vitamin A, .14mg thiamin,
>   .13mg riboflavin, 1.2mg niacin, 49mg
>   vitamin C.

One difference not captured in that breakdown is that the glycemic index is quite different at 85 (high) for white potato and 54 (medium) for sweet potato.

Comment: Hmm.. The glycemic index would indicate, that this substitution wouldn't be recomended, if it's weight loss one is after.

Comment: @Janis I tend to agree, since I lean low-carb/low-glycemic in my diet thinking.